# To Create Additional record when related to field in task is added with multiple contacts

Tags: trigger

When I log a call in activity from a contact record,in the related to field if multiple contacts are added, then records has to be created multiple times. Eg: If I add 3 contacts in Related to Field, then 3 records has to be created in salesforce. When I report it should show 3 records. Is it possible to do .

Please help as this is important.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check to see if your org has Shared Activities enabled and it sounds as though that's the case. When it's been enabled, there's a `TaskWhoIds` field that's of Type `junctionIdlist` which is a string array of contact or lead IDs related to the task.

This JunctionIdList field is linked to the TaskWhoRelations child relationship. TaskWhoIds is only available when the shared activities setting is enabled. The first contact or lead ID in the list becomes the primary WhoId if you don’t specify a primary WhoId.

So, if you have that enabled, the only way to to create individual Task Records for each contact is by entering the WhoIds into separate Tasks as the RelatedTo or `WhoId`.

An option you could try would be to clone them, remove the other contacts, then perform an update/save on each the clones. You could presumably write a trigger to do this automatically for you whenever a new Task is saved where the Activity is a Call.